# Loading a MapBox Map in XCode: error code -1002 and loading style failed: unsupported URL

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I am trying to open a simple map in XCode using MapBox. The build is successful but the simulator is only a black screen with the mapbox logo and the i at the bottom, no map loads.

**Simulator**

[image]

When I click the i, I get the option to accept to make mapbox better.

This is the errors I am receiving

**Error**

2018-09-21 19:14:40.602675-0600 MyApp[6440:163676] Task .<1> finished with error - code: -1002
2018-09-21 19:14:40.607725-0600 MyApp[6440:163676] Task <5FAF9245-6D0F-4E85-A71D-9301AEDC9961>.<2> finished with error - code: -1002
2018-09-21 19:14:40.613121-0600 MyApp[6440:163676] Task <5BD45724-540E-4013-A791-58FD205C12A5>.<1> finished with error - code: -1002
2018-09-21 19:14:40.624911-0600 MyApp[6440:163676] Task <184ADD8B-5960-4A4A-BC46-96B242FE312F>.<3> finished with error - code: -1002
2018-09-21 19:14:40.625523-0600 MyApp[6440:163676] Task <81EC417B-2515-4C1D-82B3-2D4F7E8DFF19>.<4> finished with error - code: -1002
2018-09-21 19:14:40.650401-0600 MyApp[6440:163676] Task <8EE70CCC-25AD-499B-8C56-0E62DB086DA5>.<2> finished with error - code: -1002
2018-09-21 19:14:40.662595-0600 MyApp[6440:163559] [INFO] {}[General]: GPU Identifier: Apple Software Renderer
2018-09-21 19:14:40.987888-0600 MyApp[6440:163559] [ERROR] {}[Setup]: loading style failed: unsupported URL
2018-09-21 19:14:40.996777-0600 MyApp[6440:163559] [ERROR] {}[Setup]: loading style failed: unsupported URL
2018-09-21 19:14:42.122724-0600 MyApp[6440:163642] [] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork: 308

And this is my code

**viewcontroller.swift**

import Mapbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10")
        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: url)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 59.31, longitude: 18.06), zoomLevel: 9, animated: false)
        view.addSubview(mapView)

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added your MGLMapboxAccessToken to your Info.plist file?

Comment: I did, I deleted the project and remade it and the problem was fixed, thank-you

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this issue, but you can also set your Mapbox style URL using either `MGLStyle.streetsStyleURL(withVersion: 10)` or `MGLStyle.streetsStyleURL` (which currently uses version 10).